# »geschmalzen« als Alternative zum Ausdruck »ins Geld gehen«

Tags: word-usage, word-choice, synonym

> Die Häuser gehen ins Geld im Staate Kalifornien.
>
> Die Häuser sind geschmalzen im Staate Kalifornien.

Ist ***geschmalzen*** ein Dialekt oder Hochdeutsch?

Comment: Ich kenne _gesalzene Preise_, nicht aber _geschmalzene …_, würde also auf Dialekt tippen. Ich befürchte aber, dass beide Wendungen für _viel kosten / teuer sein_ hier nicht ganz korrekt verwendet werden.

Comment: Duden sagt 'umgangssprachlich' http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/schmalzen

Comment: Possibly regional? Like @Crissov, I've heard (and used) "gesalzen". Also "diese Preise haben sich gewaschen", but "geschmalzen"?!

Comment: Um beim Würzen zu bleiben: *gepfeffert* geht auch.

Comment: Also wenn hier jetzt jemand mit "gechillit", "gecurryt" oder "geminzsossend" kommt, dann hört der Spass auf! ;)

Comment: @Marakai Die Pfefferminzsoße ist zu viel, das arme Schwein Y__Y

Comment: @Jan Vielleicht mit etwas warmem Bier?

Answer (score 1):

Zumindest in Österreich ist der Ausdruck »geschmalzene Preise« eine sehr alltägliche Floskel, die man beinahe täglich lesen oder hören kann, wie folgende Beispiele belegen:

- auflagenstarkes Wochenmagazin »News«:
  [Geschmalzene Preise: Österreichern wird noch immer Geld aus den Taschen gezogen!](http://www.news.at/a/geschmalzene-preise-oesterreichern-geld-taschen-235923)
- Qualitäts-Tageszeitung »Der Standard«:
  [Beachtliches Leistungsniveau, geschmalzene Preise](http://derstandard.at/900393/Beachtliches-Leistungsniveau-geschmalzene-Preise)
- Verbrauchermagazin »Konsument«:
  [Ersatzteile: Geschmalzene Preise Ohrhörer](http://www.konsument.at/bild-ton/ersatzteile-geschmalzene-preise)
- österreichische öffentlich-rechtliche Rundfunkanstalt »ORF«:
  [Geschmalzene Preise in Salzburger Skihütten](http://help.orf.at/stories/1732532/)
- Nachrichtenagentur »Pressetext« mit einer Aussendung der AK (Arbeiterkammer):
  [AK-Test: Geschmalzene Preisunterschiede bei Pauschalreisen](http://www.pressetext.com/news/20030411018)

Im Österreichischen Deutsch gehört der Ausdruck »geschmalzene Preise« ganz klar zum hochdeutschen (standarddeutschen) Wortschatz, und ist nicht nur in der Umgangssprache oder im Dialekt anzutreffen (dort natürlich auch).

Außer Preisen (Plural von Preis) kann in dieser übertragenen Bedeutung aber kaum etwas geschmalzen sein. Insbesondere ist der zweite Satz aus dem Beispiel in der Frage falsch:

falsch:

> <del>Die Häuser sind geschmalzen</del> im Staate Kalifornien.

korrektes österreichisches Hochdeutsch:

> Die Häuser haben **geschmalzene Preise** im Staate Kalifornien.
>   **Die Preise** der Häuser **sind geschmalzen** im Staate Kalifornien.

Ein geschmalzener Preis ist nichts anderes als ein unverschämt hoher Preis.

Schmalz ist das Bauchfett von Schweinen, dass durch Erhitzen flüssig gemacht wurde (diesen Vorgang nennt man »Auslassen«). Dieses klare, heiße, flüssige Fett wird dann in Gläser oder Töpfe abgefüllt, wo es zu einer weißen, weichen und wachsartigen Masse erstarrt, die an Butter erinnert. Beim Auslassen entstehen auch braune, knusprige Ausflockungen, die man Grammeln nennt, und entweder im Schmalz belässt (was man dann Grammelschmalz nennt), oder auch vom Schmalz getrennt aufbewahrt. In dieser Form ist das Bauchfett von Schweinen wesentlich länger haltbar (bei kühler Lagerung mehrere Jahre lang) als das rohe Fett.

Verwendet wird Schmalz als Brotaufstrich oder als Frittierfett. Das originale Wiener Schnitzel wird nicht in Öl, sondern in Schmalz herausgebacken. Das ergibt einen deutlich feineren Geschmack, aber leider auch sehr hohe Cholesterinwerte.

Eine heute weitgehend in Vergessenheit geratene Verwendung von Butter und Schmalz war die eines Transportschutzes für zerbrechliche Waren. Porzellan- und Glas-Fabriken pflegten ihre Produkte in Butter oder Schmalz einzugießen bevor man sie in Kisten auf Pferdekutschen lud, wo sie dann mehrere Tage lang über holprige Landstraßen transportiert wurden. Davon leitet sich unter anderem auch die Redewendung

> »Alles in Butter«

ab. Wenn das Porzellan in Butter eingegossen war, war es sicher. Da diese Art der Verpackung aber teuer ist, und nur bei teuren Waren in Frage kam, war das »schmalzen« (das Eingießen in Schmalz) die logische Erklärung für hohe Preise. Und bald ging das Wort »geschmalzen« vom Porzellan auf dessen Preis über, und so entstanden die *geschmalzenen Preise*.

Comment: In (Nord-)Deutschland heißt es übrigens _Griebenschmalz_.

Comment: Auf Englisch ist _Schmalz_ mit _lard_ gleichzusetzen, wobei Angelsachsen das fast in Ohnmacht fallen, wenn man denen erzählt wie gut das mit Grieben und Salz auf Schwarzbrot schmeckt. Was Grieben auf Englisch sind... keine Ahnung.

Comment: @Marakai Vollkommen naheliegend: *Greaves*. Wird allerdings in englischsprachigen Ländern überwiegend nicht als was Essbares betrachtet.

Comment: @tofro huh, _greaves_ kenne ich als was, was um die Beine geht. Ja ja zuviel Fantasy Literatur;)

Answer (score 0):

"Geschmalzen" is a colloquial term for "expensive" It comes from the word "Schmalz", which means as much as "fat" or "oil"... greasing things... hence the term.

Answer (score -1):

Das Wort wird im in Deutschland gesprochenen Hochdeutsch, außerhalb der Mundart praktisch nicht mehr verwendet.

Ich kenne "geschmalzen" nicht als Ausdruck für teuer, sondern eher für "alles dran, was drangehört". Natürlich ist etwas teurer, wenn es vollständig ausgestattet ist, aber die Bedeutung ist eigentlich eine andere. Ich glaube mal wieder, dass der Duden hier falsch liegt.

(Schweine-)Schmalz war früher das Standardfett zum Kochen für normale Leute und gehörte zu jedem Essen, kein Luxus, im Gegensatz zu Butter in Gegenden, in denen es nicht viel Milchwirtschaft gab. Ich kann mir nicht vorstellen, dass daraus ein Ausdruck für "teuer" entsteht, was bei "gepfeffert", abgeleitet von einem Luxusgut aus dem Orient, natürlich naheliegt.

Es gibt den Ausdruck "der ist nicht gesalzen und geschmalzen" für jemanden, der sehr unauffällig und langweilig ist.

Laut Grimmschem Wörterbuch wurde "ungeschmalzen" als Ausdruck für ungetaufte Kinder verwendet. Dort findet sich auch der schöne Ausdruck "eine wolgeschmalzne maulschellen" (An der, wie oben schon gesagt, alles dran ist, was drangehört - "Teuer" ist die wohl eher nicht)

Comment: -1 für »... praktisch nicht mehr verwendet.«. Gegenbeispiel (News ist ein auflagenstarkes österreichisches Wochenmagazin): http://www.news.at/a/geschmalzene-preise-oesterreichern-geld-taschen-235923 Der Standard ist eine hochwertige Qualitäts-Tageszeitung: http://derstandard.at/900393/Beachtliches-Leistungsniveau-geschmalzene-Preise Der Konsument ist ein Verbrauchermagazin, ebenfalls sehr seriös: http://www.konsument.at/bild-ton/ersatzteile-geschmalzene-preise

Comment: @HubertSchölnast Ich habe extra für dich eine Einfügung gemacht, danke für den Hinweis

Comment: Die Beispiele, die Google ngrams für dieses Jahrhundert für mich findet (tatsächlich nicht übermäßig viele, genau genommen 4 zeitgenössische...), sind tatsächlich alle aus österreichischer Literatur, mundartliche Zitate aus dem bairischen, oder in historischem Kontext. Bei Büchern aus dem "deutsch-hochdeutschen" Sprachraum finde ich nur Scan-Fehler von "geschmolzen"

Comment: Ich würde dir auch gerne für »*die Bedeutung ist eigentlich eine andere. Ich glaube mal wieder, dass der Duden hier falsch liegt.*« -1 geben, aber ich kann eine Antwort nicht zweimal bewerten. Die Bedeutung ist genau die, die im Duden steht. Wenn dir ein Wort nicht geläufig ist, solltest du darüber keine Antwort schreiben.

Comment: Leider kann man Kommentare auch nicht negativ bewerten. Ich habe deutlich dargestellt, dass das Grimmsche und das Dudensche Wörterbuch sich hier widersprechen (Ich hoffe, du hast das auch gelesen). Wenn dir das als Beleg nicht reicht, und du lieber die heutige Bedeutung eines Austriazismus voranstellen möchtest, kann ich dir nur raten: Auch und gerade als Österreicher, der anscheinend grossen Wert auf die  Eigenständigkeit seines Österreichischen Hochdeutsch legt, solltest du akzeptieren, dass sich daraus keine Allgemeingültigkeit ableiten lässt.

Comment: Das Wort »geschmalzen«, um das es hier geht, steht im Grimm gar nicht. »Ungeschmalzen« steht drin, aber ohne Bedeutungserklärung. Es gibt lediglich Verweise zu »schmalzen« und zu »ungesalzen«. Bei »Ungesalzen« wird nur beschrieben, dass das *nicht gesalzen* oder *salzlos* heißt. Bei »schmalzen« steht mehr, da steht unter c)β) dass »schmalzen« ein scherzhaftes Synonym für Taufe und Priesterweihe ist, woraus »geschmalzen und gesalzen« als Synonym für »getauft« abgeleitet wird. Das ist kein Widerspruch zum Duden, sondern schlichtweg eine andere Bedeutung. (wird fortgesetzt)

Comment: Fortsetzung: Das, wie wenn im Duden steht »Ein Leiter ist ein Metallstück, das Strom leitet« und im Grimm: »Ein Leiter ist eine Person in führender Position« und im Waring steht: »Als Leiter bezeichnet man eine Aufstiegshilfe aus zwei Stangen, die mit Quersprossen verbunden sind.« Das was im Grimm steht, mag schon richtig sein, aber hier geht es nicht um getaufte Kinder, sondern um hohe Preise, und darüber schweigt der Grimm. Im Duden steht aber genau die gesuchte Bedeutung.

Comment: Was merkwürdig ist, ist das obwohl der Ausdruck _geschmalzen_ in Österreich gang und gäbe ist, ich den im Bayerischen nicht kenne. _G'soizene Preise_, aber nicht _G'schmaizalne Preise_. Man lerne nie aus.